# How to make a Messagebox wait in C#?

Tags: c#, messagebox

Example: when i click on the Button i want that the Programm will wait for 4 Secons before the MessageBox pops up :)
Whats the code for that? thanks :)
i tried it with a timer but the MessageBox pops up Automaticly when i Press the Button

Comment: `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);`  Will hang your application though

Comment: Yes thanks. But i want that the MessageBox will hang out and not the Programm.

Comment: also only the MessageBox

Comment: I don't really understand.  Are you saying code like `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
MessageBox.Show(message);`
doesn't work?

Comment: Ok i try to response you my idea :)

Comment: i have a Login system via database. When i click on "login" i want that the login button have the Text "Connecting..." and then 4 seconds later the Message Box will apear  :) but when i click on Login the MessageBox Appear faster then the Text Changes. That why i want to make the Messagebox sleep for a view seconds

Comment: What's the point of delaying the message box when logging in? What does this artificial delay do for you?

Comment: @ManuelLobi, are you using WPF or WinForms?

Answer (score 2):

As [JDro04](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6499306/jdro04) pointed out, you can use `Thread.Sleep` to do delay. But your app will hang if you do it from main thread. So you can do delay in separate thread and invoke `MessageBox.Show` in the main one, here's the snippet:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory
        .StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(4000))
        .ContinueWith(
            continuationAction: _ => { MessageBox.Show("My message!"); /* put rest of your code here */ },
            cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None,
            continuationOptions: TaskContinuationOptions.None,
            scheduler: TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Comment: That's a bit of overkill.  He could just use a DispatcherTimer.

Comment: Agree. I wasn't sure whether he was using WinForms or WPF, tried to put something generic to cover both